# How do I redraw multiple child views at the same time?

Tags: android, viewgroup, redraw, android-gridlayout

I have an Android game with a `GridLayout` that contains a custom `ImageView` in each of its cells. At certain points in this game I want to redraw several of these `ImageView`s at the same time (not sequentially).

If I call invalidate() on the parent ViewGroup, the `GridLayout`, will all the child views be redrawn at the same time? Is there a different or better way to redraw several child views at the same time?

Comment: sounds a little too obvious but can't you use gridLayout.getChildAt(0).invalidate(); ?  (replace "0" with the position of the imageView), I'm not very familiar with ViewGroups so i could be wrong

Comment: @TomTsagk your suggestion will work fine for single ImageViews, but I have a series of maybe 4-8 ImageViews and I want them all to update at the same time (for example, I want an entire row of ImageViews to look like it's flashing and then disappearing, like in Tetris). I believe that when I loop through each view, similar to your suggestion, the user will see a slight delay between each redraw.

Comment: ooh I see what you mean, I'm afraid you picked the wrong way to create that. Using `GridLayout` is intended if you want its child views to behave independently, especially in the case of a game I'd advice you to create a single view (maybe a `SurfaceView`) and emulate a grid by yourself, that way you can draw any part of the screen you want at once

Comment: @TomTsagk thanks for the good advice. You learn all sorts of stuff making your first game :)  I'll look into SurfaceView or other similar options.